# RuntimeError: Unable to start Tika server on Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, apache-tika

I am trying to utilize Tika within Anaconda on my Windows 11 computer.
I have installed Tika version 1.24 and Java 8.

However, when I execute the following code, I encounter an error stating "RuntimeError: Unable to start Tika server." It is worth noting that occasionally, without any modifications or additional software installations, the code miraculously functions correctly, although I am unsure of the underlying reason for this inconsistency.

```
import tika
tika.initVM()
from tika import parser

parsedPDF = parser.from_file("file.pdf")
```

Please give me some advice on how to fix this. I've struggled for days, and any help will be much appreciated!

I tried the code below, and nothing changed.

```
import os
os.environ['TIKA_SERVER_JAR'] = 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/tika/tika-server/1.24/tika-server-1.24.jar'
import tika
from tika import parser
```

Comment: is there anythin more to the error message?Any additional output? If so, can you paste the complete error message into your question?

Comment: If you start the Tika server directly, does it start properly, or does it give an error?

What happens if you download the Tika Server jar and cache it, rather than fetching from maven each time?

Comment: @FlyingTeller Thank you so much for your kindly reply. The complete error message is just "RuntimeError: Unable to start Tika server." Before this error message pops up, I will first get several lines of message like "2023-06-19 15:22:46,602 [MainThread  ] [WARNI]  Failed to see startup log message; retrying..."

Comment: @Gagravarr Hi there, thank you for your kind reply. I wonder how can I run it directly? I'm sorry that I'm very new to this.

Comment: `java -jar tika-server.jar`

Comment: @Gagravarr running that line in my cmd, I get "Error: Unable to access jarfile tika-server.jar"

Comment: You need to pass the exact path and filename to the Tika Server jar you downloaded